# How to change default nls_date_format for oracle jdbc client

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have defined the global nls_date_format on Oracle 10.2 XE as follows:

```
alter system set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' scope=spfile;
```

When connecting on Windows, the clients override it with session specific format, so I need to run this line at the beginning of every session:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

However, I have some custom code that I can't change (jdbc code, using ojdbc14.jar), so I can't execute this line when receiving the connection. Is there a way to change the default value of nls_date_format for all jdbc connections? Perhaps adding something to the connection string, or some environment variable that I can use?

By the way, sqlplus and sqldeveloper also override the server's format with their own, but I found out how to change their defaults, so the problem is only with jdbc connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set nls date format in an after logon trigger

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, that worked for me.
The trigger that I inserted is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOGINTRG
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''';
END LOGINTRG;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283589/oracle-setting-per-user-default-scheme-not-altering-a-session on creating trigger for specific schema.

Comment: I tried this, it worked, but it slowed everything down to the point it was unsuable (select count(*) on an empty table taking several seconds !!!)

Comment: @laurent sounds to me like your problem is hiding elsewhere. We have been using this logon trigger in production with many clients for several years and there is no problem.