# Resultset.getDate() throwing exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Name of Month"

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When extracting date from database using `Resultset.getDate()`, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Name of Month".
```

I can confirm that the exception is thrown when trying to get data from a column of Oracle date datatype.

I can't paste the actual code here as it is very long. But the sample code is as given below

```
pstmnt = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    rs.getDate(column.getColName());
}
```

Please help?

As requested by Sanjay, please find the stack trace below

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MAY"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:63)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:531)
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:200)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getDateValue(OracleStatement.java:4610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getDate(OracleResultSetImpl.java:625)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getDate(OracleResultSet.java:1601)
    at quotecopy.DbConnection.getTableRows(DbConnection.java:126)
    at quotecopy.QuoteCopier.main(QuoteCopier.java:66)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MAY"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:63)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:531)
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:200)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getDateValue(OracleStatement.java:4610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getDate(OracleResultSetImpl.java:625)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getDate(OracleResultSet.java:1601)
    at quotecopy.DbConnection.getTableRows(DbConnection.java:127)
    at quotecopy.QuoteCopier.main(QuoteCopier.java:66)
```

Comment: If not the code, I think you should at least paste the stack trace.

Comment: What is the type of the column variable? Evidently it is not `ResultSetMetaData`, for the methods `getColName` and `getDataType` are not specified as methods in the interface.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds - Column is a user defined class in my project. Its irrelevant in this scenario. It was pasted by mistake and I have deleted it from my question.

Comment: @ Sanjay - I have modified my question and included stack trace. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check your query, i believe you are using `to_char` on the Date column which is causing the `getDate` unable to recognize it as a valid `Date`

Comment: Ooops... that was causing the error... Sorry for wasting your valuable time on this...:D

Answer (score 2):

please refer http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?19783-Oracle-JDBC-Date-Problem.
May be it would help you

Answer (score 0):

rs.getString() or rs.getDate() retrieves based on your database table column name. Can you verify that the column containing the date is named "Name of Month" ?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you might want to check out:

- Is the column type of this column in database really date/datetime?
- What happens when you print out `getObject()` instead of `getDate()`? Can you show us the output?
- What happens when you use column indices to retrieve the date instead of using column name?

Comment: 1. Yes its of DATE type 2. It just prints out the date for ex:17-MAY-11 3. I am getting the same error when using the column indices

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it would be worth checking for the following scenarios in the codebase:

- Reading a column that is not of type DATE in the Oracle database. [The Oracle JDBC driver maps the Oracle database type DATE to the java.sql.Date type](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm); actually it is the oracle.sql.Date type, which is a subtype of the java.sql.Date type. If you are not reading a column of type Oracle DATE, but instead a TIMESTAMP field, then you might encounter the exception. You would therefore have to use a suitable method - likely to be `getTimeStamp`, to read the data in the column.
- The NLS_DATE_FORMAT used in the database is different from the date format expected by the JDBC driver. This would either require you to change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT on creating a session, [using a logon trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client), or it would require you to use [TO_CHAR function calls](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817) with appropriate date formats in your SQL queries.
- Accessing the columns in the ResultSet in a random manner. Most JDBC drivers will expect you to read the contents of the result set, column by column starting at the first column, without allowing you to ignore any columns. If you attempted reading a column while ignoring the previous ones, then you might encounter this exception.

Comment: 1. Datatype in db is DATE 2. I have debugged the code and I can confirm that no columns are ignored