# timestamp locale in hibernate using oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, locale, datetime-format

I have an entity class which has a timestamp property.

If I save an entity instance in oracle, the corresponding timestamp column will be written into Chinese format(I am using oracle 10g with Chinese locale).

`22-8月 -11 07.04.03.926000 下午` is saved

But I want `2011-08-22 19:04:03.926`

How can change column definition or database locale setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timestamp in Oracle is a point in time. As such, there is no format stored with the data. When you retrieve data from a timestamp column, it is displayed by default in the format specified by your [NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams132.htm#REFRN10131) or [NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams133.htm#REFRN10132) session variable.

You can always use a specific format with [`to_char`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm#i1009324):

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(systimestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3') my_ts FROM dual;

MY_TS
-----------------------------
2011-08-22 14:38:48.351
```

You could also set a new default *for your session* with:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3';

Session altered

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------------------------------------
2011-08-22 14:42:23.776
```

Comment: Thanks. But NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT applies only to the current session. How can I impose it to every session in hibernate?

Comment: This is a client settings, I don't know if it is possible to set those variables in a config file of your client. You can however execute the statement at the beginning of each session or even [use a logon trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client/447965#447965).

Comment: Also note that you can use [`Locale.setDefault`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079985/nls-lang-setting-for-jdbc-thin-driver/1306042#1306042) to preset several NLS variables. Try `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)` before opening a connection. You still may have to set a specific session variable if they are not "default" for the specified territory.

Comment: @xiaohan2012 : when retrieving e timestamp from the database with Hibernate, you'll get a java.util.Date (or subclass) instance. This is just a point in time as well, without formatting. Use SimpleDateFormat to display this date as you want.