# Filtering date in oracle using ADO.NET

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I´m changing the connection of my system from ADO to ADO.NET, and the same query does no longer works:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE_FIELD = '2011-01-20'
```

in ADO.NET I raise an ora-01861 error.

There is a way to change the format that ADO.NET uses ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE_FIELD = TO_DATE('2011-01-20', 'yyyy-MM-DD')
```

should do it, you might as well use a parameterized query

Comment: Hi, I cant´change all sql codes from my system. There is a way to set this globally any where?

Comment: @paulo, I'm afraid there is no way to do it without changing the sql

Comment: There is a nls_date_format in oracle that I can set. Maybe this is the way.

Comment: [Get working with this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client)

Comment: @paulo Good to see you found a solution