# Oracle / JDBC: retrieving TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value in ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, database, datetime, jdbc, timezone

A lot have been said (and written on SO) on parts of the subject, but not in a comprehensive, complete way, so we can have one "ultimate, covering-it-all" solution for everyone to use.

I have an Oracle DB where I store date+time+timezone of global events, so original TZ must be preserved, and delivered to the client side upon request. Ideally, it could work nicely by using standard ISO 8601 "T" format which can be nicely stored in Oracle using "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" column type ("TSTZ").

Something like **'2013-01-02T03:04:05.060708+09:00'**

**All I need to do is to retrieve the above value from DB and send it to client without any manipulations.**

The problem is that Java lacks support of ISO 8601 (or any other date+time+nano+tz data type) and the situation is even worse, because Oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc6.jar) has even less support of TSTZ (as opposed to Oracle DB itself where it's well supported).

Specifically, here's what I shouldn't or cannot do:

- Any mapping from TSTZ to java Date, Time, Timestamp (e.g. via JDBC getTimestamp() calls) won't work because I lose TZ.
- Oracle JDBC driver doesn't provide any method to map TSTZ to java Calendar object (this could be a solution, but it isn't there)
- JDBC getString() could work, but Oracle JDBC driver returns string in format 
  '2013-01-02 03:04:05.060708 +9:00', which is not compliant with ISO 8601 (no "T", no trailing 0 in TZ, etc.). Moreover, this format is hard-coded (!) inside Oracle JDBC driver implementation, which also ignores JVM locale settings and Oracle session formatting settings (i.e. it ignores NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT session variable).
- JDBC getObject(), or getTIMESTAMPTZ(), both return Oracle's TIMESTAMPTZ object, which is practically useless, because it doesn't have any conversion to Calendar (only Date, Time and Timestamp), so again, we lose TZ information.

So, here are the options I'm left with:

1. Use JDBC getString(), and string-manipulate it to fix and make ISO 8601 compliant. This is easy to do, but there's a danger to die if Oracle changes internal hard-coded getString() formatting. Also, by looking at the getString() source code, seems like using getString() would also result in some performance penalty.
2. Use Oracle DB "toString" conversion: "SELECT TO_CHAR(tstz...) EVENT_TIME ...". This works fine, but has 2 major disadvatages:

   - Each SELECT now has to include TO_CHAR call which is a headache to remember and write
   - Each SELECT now has to add EVENT_TIME column "alias" (needed e.g. to serialize the result to Json automatically)

     .
3. Use Oracle's TIMESTAMPTZ java class and extract relevant value manually from its internal (documented) byte array structure (i.e. implement my own toString() method which Oracle forgot to implement there). This is risky if Oracle changes internal structure (unlikely) and demands relatively complicated function to implement and maintain.
4. I hope there's 4th, great option, but from looking all over the web and SO - I can't see any.

Ideas? Opinions?

**UPDATE**

A lot of ideas have been given below, but it looks like there is no proper way to do it. Personally, I think using **method #1** is the shortest and the most readable way (and maintains decent performance, *without losing sub-milliseconds or SQL time-based query capabilities*).

This is what I eventually decided to use:

```
String iso = rs.getString(col).replaceFirst(" ", "T");
```

Thanks for good answers everyone,
  B.

Comment: "All I need..." here be dragons.

Comment: The biggest challenge I see is that [`TSTZ` types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081) can be a date-time-offset such as the `2013-01-02T03:04:05.060708+09:00` example you gave, or they can be a date-time-timezone type, such as `2013-01-02T03:04:05.060708 Asia/Tokyo`.  Even using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) those would be two different data types.  And I'm not sure if you can use Joda directly with Oracle without going through Java native types to start with.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, since I control the inserts and the retrievals to/from DB, I can limit my system to only support +HH:MM TZO and disallow TZ-names. As for Joda etc., you're right - it will get screwed on the way from DB by Oracle driver and Joda won't help. Thanks.

Comment: I just found [this article](http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/11/02/how-to-handle-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-from-java/) that discusses this exact problem and offers a few solutions.  Perhaps it will help.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I saw that a while ago, it's indeed clean and readable. The dilemma there is similar to what I have. It's either use ridiculously complicated, heavy and buggy Calendar API (24 lines of code for insert, and similar for retrieve, plus some workarounds), or just use String, as my option #1, with all its pros and cons. Thanks.

Comment: Once you get the string to the ISO format Java's XMLGregorianCalendar will parse it into a nice object with methods such as getFractionalSecond and getTimezone.  This doesn't solve your problem but I wanted to point out that Java does have some support for the ISO format that you might find useful once you get your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like there's no magical way of doing this right, the simplest and the shortest method would be #1. Specifically, this is all the code needed:

```
// convert Oracle's hard-coded: '2013-01-02 03:04:05.060708 +9:00'
// to properly formatted ISO 8601: '2013-01-02T03:04:05.060708 +9:00'
String iso = rs.getString(col).replaceFirst(" ", "T");
```

it seems that just adding 'T' is enough, although a perfectionist would probably put more cosmetics (regex can optimized, of course), e.g.: rs.getString(col).replaceFirst(" ", "T").replaceAll(" ", "").replaceFirst("\+([0-9])\:", "+0$1:");

B.

Answer (score 5):

> JDBC getObject(), or getTIMESTAMPTZ(), both return Oracle's TIMESTAMPTZ object, which is practically useless, because it doesn't have any conversion to Calendar (only Date, Time and Timestamp), so again, we lose TZ information.

That would be my recommendation as the only reliable way to get the information you seek.

If you are on Java SE 8 and have ojdbc8 then you can use `getObject(int, OffsetDateTime.class`). Be aware that when you use `getObject(int, ZonedDateTime.class`) you may be affected by [bug 25792016](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=25792016).

> Use Oracle's TIMESTAMPTZ java class and extract relevant value manually from its internal (documented) byte array structure (i.e. implement my own toString() method which Oracle forgot to implement there). This is risky if Oracle changes internal structure (unlikely) and demands relatively complicated function to implement and maintain.

This is what we [ultimately went with](https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa/blob/master/threeten-jpa-oracle-impl/src/main/java/com/github/marschall/threeten/jpa/oracle/impl/TimestamptzConverter.java) until bug free JSR-310 support is available in the Oracle JDBC driver. We determined this was the only reliable way to get the information we want.

Comment: We use a custom mapping implementation with ojdbc7 as well and had a severe bug in it with certain TZ constellations (Mapping to UTC-Time was not done correctly). Thx for the link!

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement to #2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE FORMAT AS
  FUNCTION TZ(T TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY FORMAT AS
  FUNCTION TZ(T TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN TO_CHAR(T,'YYYYMMDD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM');
  END;
END;
/
```

The in SQL this becomes:

```
SELECT FORMAT.TZ(tstz) EVENT_TIME ...
```

It's more readable.
If you ever need to change it, it's 1 place.
The downside is it is an extra function call.

Comment: Thanks Devon, this is a nice readable code, but even without it TO_CHAR(TSTZ) will work just as fine if you add DB logon trigger which adjusts session variables controlling formatting. See here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/447965/59770). I use this method and it works like a charm (it won't solve the JDBC problem in subject though)

Answer (score 0):

you need two values: time utc in millis since 1970 and timezone offset fom utc.
So store them as a pair and forward them as a pair.

```
class DateWithTimeZone {
long timestampUtcMillis;
// offset in seconds
int tzOffsetUtcSec;
}
```

A Date is a pair of numbers. It is not a String. So a machine interface should not contain a date represented by a iso string, although that is handy to debug.
If even java cannot parse that iso date, how do you think that your clients can do?

If you design an interface to your clients, think how they can parse that. And in advance write a code that shows that.

Comment: And store this in DB as what data type? I can store them in DB as structure type, as byte array or even encode them into large NUMBER. But all these ideas will prevent me from using dates and times in SQL queries (e.g. how to I query events of a certain time period)? Or how do I order events by time, TZ-aware? etc. It's like storing the original ISO 8601 string representation as VARCHAR2 in the DB - not very useful. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with order by time tz aware? order them by utc! further in most cases you should not calculaze with tz. store all in utc, calculate in utc. only at the final step when you have to display a timestamp  in localtime in an ui convert to localtime usinf the tz. rethink your design.

Comment: Well, TZ-aware order is probably simple, you're right. But it can get really complicated. How would query a number (or a histogram) of people who leave the offices (located everywhere worldwide) between 3pm and 5pm? The big benefit of using built-in Oracle TSTZ data type is that it provides you with entire date/time arithmetic API built-in. Plus, I'm trying to avoid writing serialization/deserialization code to/from ISO 8601 format, when storing/retrieving things in DB.

Comment: you can use the TSTZ for your queries, but inside java and in all other systems, they will not like that. its very expensive to parse an iso8601, while its extremly fast to work with utcMillis and tzOffset. So i would not forward that iso8601 to another system. deserializing the TZTZ in the structure I gave in my answer, makes it faster for other system to process the data. and further the iso8601 string needs much more bytes. Some other DB even dont have a TZ support in their DATE representtaions.

Comment: Further in your example, the resulting histogram should not contain the TZTZ on the x-axis, instead it should be number of seconds since start of day (00:00). So for such special queries, special interfcaes have to be created, if you want to forward that result.

Comment: Thanks Alex. In any case, as I mentioned, I don't have (and don't want to) to have any significant code in Java layer (so nothing to optimize there), and my client systems all must accept ISO format. I'm looking for as-transparent-as-possible DB->Client TSTZ transmission.

Comment: To demand from a client a full compatible iso8601 parser is one of the worst interfaces I have ever heard, If even java cannot parse that how do you think that your clients can do? forget that iso. Machines do not need and don't want a human readable timeformat. design a machine readable format that is totally easy to parse, like utcMillis + TZ offset in seconds. It's your lazyness that result in such horrible interfaces, which costs the client at least  100 times the processing power

Comment: Alex, clients don't use Java (why should they?). Except Java, all other environments/frameworks support ISO format perfectly, including all the arithmetic which comes with it. Besides, I do not demand anything from client. Clients exist today and they demand from me to provide ISO format, a demand I cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but seems like it ought to be a workable approach.  I'm not sure about parsing the TZ name out, but just treating the two parts of the TZTZ object as separate inputs to Calendar seems like the was to go.

I'm not sure whether longValue() will return the value in local or GMT/UCT.  If it's not GMT, you should be able to load a calendar as UTC and ask it for a Calendar converted to local TZ.

```
public Calendar toCalendar(oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ myOracleTime) throws SQLException {
    byte[] bytes = myOracleTime.getBytes();
    String tzId = "GMT" + ArrayUtils.subarray(bytes, ArrayUtils.lastIndexOf(bytes, (byte) ' '), bytes.length);
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(myOracleTime.longValue());
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: This is the same direction as option #3 that I described (get TSTZ object and parse it using custom code). There are 2 problems with this approach: (a) you lose nanoseconds (and microseconds); and (b) the actual TSTZ byte structure is more complicated, you need do apply some additional manipulations for this to work. See how Oracle themselve are doing this: [(look for getString)](http://ora-jdbc-source.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/jdbc/driver/TimestamptzAccessor.java). I think it's possible but a bit too heavy (and a bit risky) for such a simple task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care about sub-millisecond precision?  If not converting from a UTC millisecond + timezone-offset to your required string is a one-liner using joda-time:

```
    int offsetMillis = rs.getInt(1);
    Date date = rs.getTimestamp(2);

    String iso8601String =
            ISODateTimeFormat
                    .dateTime()
                    .withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(offsetMillis))
                    .print(date.getTime());
```

Prints, for example (current time in +9:00):

```
2013-07-18T13:05:36.551+09:00
```

Regarding the database:  Two columns, one for the offset, one for the date.  The date column could be an actual date type (thus making many, timezone-independent anyway, db date functions available).  For time-zone dependent queries (such as the mentioned global hourly histogram) perhaps a view could expose columns: local_hour_of_day, local_minute_of_hour, etc.

This is likely how one would have to do it if no TSTZ datatype was available--which, considering Oralce's poor support, is the nearly the case for practical purposes.  Who wants to use an Oracle specific features anyway!  :-)

Comment: Keith, I do care about sub-millis. Also, TSTZ column allows using built-in TSTZ arithmetic in SQL queries, which is a nice extra. The irony is that Oracle DB itself DOES have good support for TSTZ (and there's fantastic support for TSTZ in any modern DB). The problem is in the really-badly-written Oracle's JDBC driver. Thanks.

Answer (score -5):

The solution with oracle is SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL