# Troubles with converting oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ to string value

Tags: java, json, oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I try get some data from oracle db, put this data in json and use it in other place, but i have problem with converting timestamptz. Oracle give me timestamp with timezone in string format like "23.10.14 18:34:16,000000 ASIA/NOVOSIBIRSK". Here some piece of my code.

```
public void loadFromDb(ResultSet resultSet, Connection oc) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        Object obj = resultSet.getObject(i);
        if (obj == null)
            continue;
        if (obj instanceof TIMESTAMPTZ) {
            TIMESTAMPTZ ts = (TIMESTAMPTZ) obj;
            if (oc != null) {
                super.setValue(metaData.getColumnName(i), ts.stringValue(oc));
            } else {
                super.setValue(metaData.getColumnName(i), ts.stringValue());
            }
    }
}
```

and i get this exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Conversion to String failed
at oracle.sql.Datum.stringValue(Datum.java:181)
```

btw, earlier i get timezone in number format like 'XX:XX' and this code not work too, but work this magic `super.setValue(metaData.getColumnName(i), ts.stringValue(null))`now this way thtows nullpointerexception. 
Please help me, because i tried all which found in javadocs.

Comment: There can be some problems with your jdbc driver + have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559658/oracle-jdbc-retrieving-timestamp-with-time-zone-value-in-iso-8601-format

Comment: I think that the easiest way to solve the problem is to retrieve string representation of timestamp with time zone (if it's possible in your case)

Comment: @Multisync maybe i missunderstand you but this my problem - get  string representation of timestamp with time zone

Comment: I mean select to_char(col_timestamp_with_time_zone, 'format') ... Which format do you need?

Comment: @Multisync i cant do anything in db side. i just call procedure which return some resultset. thanks for you link, i think that #4(write own toString()) is one possible way for my situation....

Comment: It can be dangerous because Oracle can generate different representations of this type depending on database/session settings. If you call a function which return a cursor you may represent this call as select from table and make a conversation on the oracle side.

Comment: No, I wasn't right. Seems it's impossible without touching a db: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690110/function-return-sys-refcursor-call-from-sql-with-specific-columns Then I would recommend an answer which was awarded +50 because it takes into consideration different formats Oracle may return

Answer (score 1):

The format of `TIMESTAMPTZ` is [well documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html). We currently use [the following code](https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa/blob/master/threeten-jpa-oracle-impl/src/main/java/com/github/marschall/threeten/jpa/oracle/impl/TimestamptzConverter.java).

If you are on Java SE 8 and ojdbc8 you can use `getObject(int, OffsetDateTime.class)`. If you use `getObject(int, ZonedDateTime.class)` you may be affected by [bug 25792016](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=25792016).

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP` is not a string and vice-versa. You need to convert it into a string using `TO_CHAR` and desired format.

```
SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP
  2  FROM   dual
  3  /

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
24-OCT-14 11.14.55.116000 AM +05:30

SQL>
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') tm
  2  FROM dual
  3  /

TM
-------------------------------------
24-OCT-2014 11:14:55.163000 +05:30

SQL> SELECT to_timestamp_tz('24-OCT-2014 11:07:40.348000 +05:30','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') tm
  2  FROM dual
  3  /

TM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
24-OCT-14 11.07.40.348000000 AM +05:30

SQL> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('24-OCT-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  2  FROM dual
  3  /

TO_TIMESTAMP('24-OCT-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
24-OCT-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

Let's validate.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    tm_stamp  TIMESTAMP;
  3    tm_string VARCHAR2(30);
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP INTO tm_stamp FROM dual;
  6    dbms_output.put_line(tm_stamp);
  7    SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP INTO tm_string FROM dual;
  8    dbms_output.put_line(tm_string);
  9  END;
 10  /
24-OCT-14 11.17.35.180000 AM
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 7


SQL>
```

So, tm_string cannot store timestamp, since tm_stamp is a string type and not timestamp.

The correct way is to convert it into string explicitly.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    tm_stamp  TIMESTAMP;
  3    tm_string VARCHAR2(50);
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') INTO tm_string FROM dual;
  6    dbms_output.put_line(tm_string);
  7  END;
  8  /
24-OCT-2014 11:25:20.060000 +05:30

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks, but i limited resource of java, because i cant do anything in db side. i just call procedure which return some resultset.