# Oracle error code [17004] Invalid column type for java.time.Instant

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp-with-timezone, ora-17004

I get the following exception while trying to store instance of `java.time.Instant` into Oracle table where the column is of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested
>   exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type] with root
>   cause
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Have tried with `java.time.OffsetDateTime` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime` and all of them gives the same exception.

Please let me know what type can I store to this column by preserving the timezone details.

Comment: According to JDBC 4.2 it should be `OffsetDateTime`. Is your driver JDBC 4.2 compliant? Some drivers also accept `Instant`, I don’t know about the Oracle driver.

Comment: Related to [Oracle / JDBC: retrieving TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value in ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559658/oracle-jdbc-retrieving-timestamp-with-time-zone-value-in-iso-8601-format) (though that is old and possibly no longer relevant)

Comment: should at least work with `java.sql.Timestamp`