# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month when calling a procedure

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, sysdate

I have application which has a procedure as follows:

```
procedure get_full_data (list OUT sys_refcursor,id in number, 
                                   code in varchar2,type in varchar2) is
      year_in number;                                
begin
    year_in := to_number(to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RRRR'),'RRRR')); // line 628
        open list for
        select * from my_tab 
        where code_present = code AND to_number(substr(year,1,4)) in (year_in,year_in-1,year_in-2)
        and minth in(select max(month) from my_tab where code_present = code
                         and to_number(substr(year,1,4)) in (year_in,year_in-1,year_in-2)
                         group by substr(year,1,9))
        order by to_number(substr(year,1,4)) desc;
END get_full_data;
```

And Here's the Java code which calls this procedure (I'm using `hibernate` over here):

```
List<MyBean> salesApproval=session.getNamedQuery("get_data").setInteger("id",my_id).setString("code",my_code).setString("type",my_type).list();
```

`MyBean` is the class holds the data returned by procedure.

**Problem:**
When I host my application on `windows` system it works fine with desired result.
However when I host my application on `Linux Ubuntu 12.04`, it gives following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at "db.proc_pack", line 628
```

Line number 628 is mentioned in procedure.

Comment: Try `year_in := (select to_number(to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RRRR'),'RRRR')) from dual);`

Comment: But how come it works on windows and not in linux?

Comment: Your comment will anyway not work. It would require `select ... into from dual`.

Answer (score 2):

```
year_in := to_number(to_char(sysdate,'RRRR')); // line 628
```

`SYSDATE` is already returning date, so `TO_DATE()` conversion on it goes wrong..

To understand why the error is.. `TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'...')` will become `TO_DATE('Date in Default Format','YOUR FORMAT');` So, more chances of it to go wrong..

Your default format will be `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of your session! This depend on the platform and session parameters in different hosts!

**Example:**

```
SQL> SELECT value FROM   nls_database_parameters WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR

SQL>  select to_date(sysdate,'MON-DD-RR') from dual;
 select to_date(sysdate,'MON-DD-RR') from dual
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'MON-DD-RR';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date(sysdate,'MON-DD-RR') from dual;

TO_DATE(S
---------
AUG-29-14
```

[Oracle Document Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm)

Comment: OK my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is already `DD-MON-RRRR` on linux. And anyway I am converting my date to that format using `to_date(sysdate,'DD-MIN-RRRR')`, so I don't see it to be conflicting formats.

Comment: @DarshanLila I added an example.

Comment: But I am already formatting sysdate as `to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RRRR')` which is compatible to `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. However the procedure works fine when i execute it from sqldeveloper, but generates exception when I try to call it through hibernate.

Comment: @DarshanLila `TO_DATE()` accept a String and convert into the date into some format. So your to_date() conversion is not needed here. `SYSDATE` is already a date. And the reason for the error I explained above. You need to [ALTER your NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client) in jdbc or any where..if at all you want it to work consistently.

Comment: How do you know that? I added more output samples! It is different in java and sql developer. Perhaps, You are checking in sql developer and assuming it to be same in java?

Comment: I've checked nls_parameter in sql developer, it was DD-MON-RRRR

Comment: Oops.. It is SQL session parameter .. not a database parameter itself.. SQL Developer's session might have some pre-defined params, which will not be same with Hibernate! try to run the query to find the nls value in Hibernate, and you will find it!

Comment: Sure I'll check that, there's possibility of a problem there.

Comment: I checked in hibernate the format is `DD-MON-RR` so there are surely no conflicts there.

Comment: Bro, the error what I mean is right.! You can try my examples. I don't see any other issues. And try to explicitly run the alter query before executing your proc.