# Oracle NLS_DATE_FORMAT using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I have problem with NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

I was run this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24: MI: SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24: MI: SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24: MI: SSXFF';
```

On server show sysdate => 2016-01-18 => OK

But when I run SQL script from java, It always show 18-FEB-16.
How to change to 2016-01-18 without edit my source code.?

Comment: Please show your java code, since this `18-FEB-16` representation may be because of the format that you are printing out the returned `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` or ...  objects not the format of the database.

Comment: My code call a Oracle's proceduce and it shown "18-FEB-16" in Proceduce

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the JAVA specific configuration, but you could create an after **logon** trigger at DB to alter the NLS configuration:

[How to change default nls_date_format for oracle jdbc client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOGINTRG
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
   if user = 'MYUSER' then -- if you can do that better
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''';
   end if;
END LOGINTRG;
```

I would suggest adding a if statement to just do that when the connected user is the one your application uses.