# nHibernate default schema unused in formula

Tags: nhibernate, schema, properties, formula

Hey Guys,
 I'm using nhibernate 2.2 and ran into a problem that I can't seem to find an answer to.  My program is using a default schema assigned in the hibernate.cfg.xml file like this:
`<property name="default_schema">MY_SCHEMA</property>`
which works as advertised for all generated SQL statements, however I have statements in a formula that need to be assigned the default schema as well: 
`<property name="Count" type="int" formula="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DETAILS WHERE DETAILS.ID = ID" />`
MY_SCHEMA changes relatively often, so I need the SQL to be interpreted as `<property name="Count" type="int" formula="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_SCHEMA.DETAILS WHERE DETAILS.ID = ID" />`
Is this possible without resorting to hardcoded schemas?  Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: use logon trigger 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283589/oracle-setting-per-user-default-scheme-not-altering-a-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your mappings on the fly when building the session factory.

Of course that's easier to do if you use a code-based mapping solution, like Fluent or ConfORM.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I understand how you change the mappings inside session factory and that is where my current default_schema is defined.  My problem is that since the formula isn't "generated SQL" nHibernate is not applying the default_schema to unqualified table names as it does for everything else.  Is there a way to pull the current default from the config file or perhaps to tell nHibernate to process the formula as it would generated SQL?

Comment: Maybe my answer wasn't clear enough. What I'm suggesting is that you **modify the formula** when creating the configuration.

Comment: Sadly we're constrained to the use of the basic xml files and aren't making the configurations dynamically.

Comment: You can still load the XML mapping in memory, look for the formula, change it, and add the mapping using the Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument) overload. There are many solutions. I can't guess what your artificial constraints are.

Comment: Got it figured out along those lines, it won't be elegant, but I'm not sure there is a perfect solution within my constraints. Thanks for your help!