# Oracle: Change Schema based on role

Tags: oracle, triggers, schema

There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283589/oracle-setting-per-user-default-scheme-not-altering-a-session) that describes setting up a trigger to change the schema on login. Is there a way to check the role of the user to see if it matches a specific role instead of the username itself?

I tried to do a subquery to user_role_privs in the when clause, but it doesn't allow that. Ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is what I'm using per Yahia's suggested solution. It does not seem to be working though. When I login with a user with the role, it still does not recognize the table without the schema name before it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER db_logon
AFTER logon ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM user_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'USER_ROLE' and username <> 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA';
    IF v_count > 0 THEN
        execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = DEFAULT_SCHEMA';
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - ditch the WHEN part and build the SQL string inside the trigger dynamically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER db_logon
AFTER logon ON DATABASE
```

Use the `SELECT` on `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` and map whatever you want from the `ROLE` to a `SCHEMA`.

Then build an SQL string for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` including the mapped `SCHEMA`.

Comment: That seems stupidly obvious once you say it. I am having an issue getting it to work though. Updating post with what I'm using.

Comment: It works when I remove the if statement and just always force it to the schema. Can't see what is wrong with the if statement though. The select count returns 1 when I run it as the user.

Comment: For some reason, I got it to work once I removed the AND username <> 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA' from the where clause even though that whole query works when logged in as the user. Considering it fixed. Thanks