# Are connection specific variables in Oracle SQL Developer possible?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

I have two connections I use a lot that have two schemas that are basically the same but named different, say `FOO` and `BAR` for the Foo and Bar connection respectively. My queries looks like this basically...

```
select Stuff from FOO.CoolTable; -- For Foo connection
select Stuff from BAR.CoolTable; -- For Bar connection
```

What I end up doing is writing both and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the one I need after switching connections (or switching back and forth manually).

**What I want to know is if there is some way to have some kind of variable specific to the connection so I can only write one and when I run the query it chooses the right schema based on connection.**

Something like this:

```
select Stuff from <my_var>.CoolTable;
```

Where `<mr_var>` is read as the text "`FOO`" for the Foo connection and "`BAR`" for the Bar connection.

Similar to the idea of environment variables if that helps clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in sqldeveloper for what you need.

However you could use a logon trigger on the database to set a default schema for your login. This way you can fire queries without using the qualifying schema name, just: `select Stuff from CoolTable`

To setup logon trigger: [Oracle setting per user default scheme (not altering a session)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283589/oracle-setting-per-user-default-scheme-not-altering-a-session)

Comment: Not sure if I have permissions to do this, is there a way to run a command on log in through Oracle Dev? (Embarrassingly I didn't know `set schema` was a thing.) If not I can maybe convince our DBA to do this.

Comment: You need privileges to do this so treat your dba to a coffee :)

Comment: I brought bagels this morning for the dev and ops teams, we include them for a reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about substitution variables ?

In the frist connection just do:

```
 define myschema = foo
```

and in the second connection:

```
 define myschema = bar
```

And the query may look like this:

```
select * from &myschema..tablename;
```

I've tested it on SQL Developer, and it requires two dots between `&myschema` and the table name, there was a syntax error when I used only one dot, I don't know why.